# Nativescript get element position

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

Is there a way to get the element's current position? it's x and y.or offsetTop. I tried `getLocationOnScreen` and `getLocationInWindow` but the result was undefined.
also I tried `this.el.nativeElement.offsetTop` but result was same.

Comment: try using the above value but with some additional timeout (using setTimeout) or via the loaded event for the element you are trying to measure. The Angular lifecycles events are often triggered BEFORE the native elements which might be the reason for your undefined values (the measurerment is not over)

Comment: Do it upon `layoutChanged` event, that should give you the expected results. If you still find any issues, please share a Playground sample.

Comment: Thank you friends. sure here is the playground: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=33o2rX&v=7